# Configuring Virtual Topics

Tags: activemq-classic

I am trying to get a simple example of Virtual Topics working but I am failing miserably.

From what I have read the documentation may be incorrect on the activemq site.

My C# is as follows:

```
I have a consumer connect to queue://Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.FOO
I have a producer connect to topic://VirtualTopic.FOO
The producer publishes a message
```

My server config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/activemq/apollo">

  <notes>
    The default configuration with tls/ssl enabled.
  </notes>

  <log_category console="console" security="security" connection="connection" audit="audit"/>


  <authentication domain="apollo"/>
  <!-- Give admins full access -->
  <access_rule allow="admins" action="*"/>
  <access_rule allow="*" action="connect" kind="connector"/>


  <virtual_host id="mybroker">
    <!--
      You should add all the host names that this virtual host is known as
      to properly support the STOMP 1.1 virtual host feature.
      -->
    <host_name>mybroker</host_name>
    <host_name>localhost</host_name>
    <host_name>127.0.0.1</host_name>

    <!-- Uncomment to disable security for the virtual host -->
    <!-- <authentication enabled="false"/> -->

    <!-- Uncomment to disable security for the virtual host -->
    <!-- <authentication enabled="false"/> -->
    <access_rule allow="users" action="connect create destroy send receive consume"/>


    <!-- You can delete this element if you want to disable persistence for this virtual host -->
    <leveldb_store directory="${apollo.base}/data"/>


  </virtual_host>

  <web_admin bind="http://127.0.0.1:61680"/>
  <web_admin bind="https://127.0.0.1:61681"/>

  <connector id="tcp" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61613" connection_limit="2000"/>
  <connector id="tls" bind="tls://0.0.0.0:61614" connection_limit="2000"/>
  <connector id="ws"  bind="ws://0.0.0.0:61623"  connection_limit="2000"/>
  <connector id="wss" bind="wss://0.0.0.0:61624" connection_limit="2000"/>

  <key_storage file="${apollo.base}/etc/keystore" password="password" key_password="password"/>

    <destinationInterceptors>
      <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
        <virtualTopic name="VirtualTopic.>" prefix="Consumer.*."/> 
        </virtualDestinations>
      </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>  

</broker>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @MegaIng I was the problem. I did not realize that ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ Apollo were different. I was able to work through the issue. Thanks for reaching out though.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. I am using activemq apollo which is different from activemq. The configurations are different but the server does not complain if you give it bogus configs. The apollo configs are documented here: https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/user-manual.html. I needed to add a  element with mirrored option set to true in the  element.

Comment: Apollo is not longer being developed and should not be used for serious work, instead use ActiveMQ proper or ActiveMQ Artemis which is the most actively developed at this time.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am also considering Kafka as I understand it is more actively being developed and offers a robust feature set. Any thoughts on Kafka?